# Linux Mint, Backspace Key and open two steps parent directory

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a weird problem that I can not figure out how to solve it. When I press the backspace at caja (Mate Enviroment), the current director goes up not one step parent directory, but two steps. Ex. Current dir is /home/user/Documents/, when I press backspace at caja, curr directory goes /home/.  It is very annoying. How can I fixed it or how should I google it?

Description: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

```
>>xinput:
....
Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard id=10 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys id=13 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse id=11 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: I editted my question. I mean the backspace acts twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [palordrolap](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/do6aza/question_double_backspace_and_open_the_parent_dir/f5k6j37?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), Increasing key delay and key repeat solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks to me :)